# What's the best way to run a visibility analysis in PostGIS 2?

Tags: postgis, visibility

I am looking for the best way to run a visibility analysis in PostGis 2, i.e. given 2 points and obstacle polygons, are these 2 points visible from each other ?

I did not find anything relevant for now. Are you aware of :

- such a function
- a library I could use to perform this
- or do I have to implement it by myself ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not one which im aware, but SAGA has one , GRASS has one, QGIs has one in SEXTANTE toolbox. Probably easiest way would be use grass or saga from commandline to calculate it. Also i think all mentioned programs have open source

Comment: Is this a 2D analysis?

Comment: Yes this is a 2d analysis

Comment: Why do you want to do it in PostGIS and not in a "real" GIS? If you were using (as mentioned) grass or QGIS, it would be very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with SQL. Without knowing how you're getting your data, I'd guess something like:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects([the polygon geom], ST_LineFromWKB([point A geom], [point B geom])) AS Is_Obscured
```

Obviously this is not a complete query. If it's not enough to point you in the right direction, then you'll need to share some more details.

Comment: It seems there is ST_3DIntersects. using that requires 3d data... But after reading that 2D comment i assume that Z dosent affect visibility

Comment: I made the same assumption.  Another assumption here is that the distances are short enough to ignore the whole geometry vs. geography great circle issue.

Comment: But then you can cast (or transform) geometry to geography (i think)